# Remove All inline style from text in MSSQL

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, regex

i want remove all  inline style from `[Contnent]` in **MSSQLSERVER**
clean everything from  style="*"

**for ex:**
`<div style="color:red;font-size:12px;"> test <i style="color:blue;" > 2 </i> </div>`

TO:
`<div> test <i> 2 </i> </div>`

Comment: seems SQL Server doesn't support regex natively, do you know which regex engine will be used, it may be possible or not, more or less robust, depending on engine capabilities.

Comment: my sql version is 2014 and when i install sql i select all feature .

Comment: sql server does not support regex

Comment: so please help me to create function that remove all string between two string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, it's useful to define function to remove all tags:

```
create function RemoveStyles(@html varchar(1000)) returns varchar(1000) as
begin

declare @tagIndex int
set @tagIndex = CHARINDEX(' style=', @html)

while @tagIndex > 0
begin
    set @html = SUBSTRING(@html, 1, @tagIndex - 1) + SUBSTRING(@html, CHARINDEX('"', @html, @tagIndex + 8) + 1, LEN(@html))
    set @tagIndex = CHARINDEX(' style=', @html)
end
return @html
end
```

Then your query will become very simple (I created my function in `master` database):

```
select master.dbo.RemoveStyles([Content]) from MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

i found this function but it remove STYLE tag

```
  create FUNCTION [dbo].CleanHTML(@HTMLText varchar(MAX))
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Start  int
DECLARE @End    int
DECLARE @Length int


SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<STYLE', @HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('</STYLE>', @HTMLText, CHARINDEX('<', @HTMLText)) + 7
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1

WHILE (@Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0) BEGIN
SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '')
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<STYLE', @HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('</STYLE>', @HTMLText, CHARINDEX('</STYLE>', @HTMLText)) + 7
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
END


RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))

END
```